# Adding fields on button click

Tags: java, javafx, label

I need to add a bunch of Labels and TextFields on button click.
In this case I need to add them as code right, not in the FXML?

I have Automobile class and I have to add like 10 labels and text fields when the user clicks a "Add Automobile" button.
Is there a better way than adding them like this:

```
Label label = new Label("State registration number:");
TextField textField1 = new TextField();
Label label2 = new Label("Brand:");
TextField textField2 = new TextField();
Label label3 = new Label("Model:");
TextField textField3 = new TextField();
Label label4 = new Label("Year of production:");
```

And so on... And if I need to add to them some other attributes, I need to write like 30+ more lines. Is there a better way of doing this? What is the best practice?

Comment: You do not add anything in your code snippet. Depending on the layout/scene structure you use there could be a way of doing this that requires less repeated code, but that depends. Could you add info about what you're doning with those objects except for creating them?

Comment: Hello @fabian, thanks for your reply!
I have a scene with three buttons - for adding, updating and deleting an automobile. If the user clicks on the adding button, I want to create labels and text fields, so the user can enter the automobile's data. Then it will add it to a database.

Comment: Now when the user wants to update an automobile's data, he should click on the updating button. Then I want to clear all the labels and text fields and to create a combo box for the user to choose
which automobile to update. After he chooses the automobile's registration number, I want to recreate
all the labels and textfield with the chosen automobile's data inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the greatest solution but a good base to start with

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultipleLabelTextFiledApp extends Application {
    private final ObservableList<CustomControl> customControls = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final List<String> labels = Arrays.asList("label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        labels.stream().forEach(label -> customControls.add(new CustomControl(label)));

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().setAll(customControls);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();

        getCustomControl("label1").ifPresent(customControl -> {
            customControl.getTextField().textProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<String>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                System.out.println("textField with label1 handler new text=" + newValue);
            });
        });
    }

    private Optional<CustomControl> getCustomControl(String labelText) {
        return customControls.stream()
        .filter(customControl -> labelText.equals(customControl.getLabel().getText()))
        .findFirst();
    }
}

class CustomControl extends HBox {

    private final Label label = new Label();
    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    {
        getChildren().addAll(label, textField);
    }

    public CustomControl(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }

    public Label getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public TextField getTextField() {
        return textField;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

First what you need is an int variable which its value is the amount of labels and textfields you want to create, it would be:

```
int amount = 10;
```

You should declare three arrays: One wich contains the text of the labels it would be:

```
String [] text_labels = new String [] {"State registration number:", "Brand:", "Model:", "..."};
```

Then you should declare the second array which may be:

```
Label [] labels = new Label[amount];
```

And the third one:

```
TextField [] textfields = new Text field[amount];
```

Once you haved declared them you have to initialize the labels and textfields. In order to do so you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i ++) {
  Label label = new Label(text_labels[i]);
  TextField textField = new TextField();
  labels[i] = label;
  textfields[i] = textField;
}
```

So labels[0] would be the same as the first label you wrote in your code and the same with the textfields.

Comment: You're not allowed to specify the number of items in java, if you're initializing the array. Furthermore you're not allowed to specify the number of items in the declaration. Arrays are created using `new ElementType[elementCount]` or `new ElementType[] { ...values... }`; `new String[1] {"Hello World"}` yields a compile time error though...

Comment: True, I'm going to change it